# The Math class does not appear to exist

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, math

I think I broke my Flash. I'm using Flash CS5.5, and when I use AS3, any references to the Math class give me errors like this:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method sqrt through a reference with static type Class.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method pow through a reference with static type Class.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method pow through a reference with static type Class.
```

The code in error is this:

```
var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initPos.x - pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(initPos.y - pos.y, 2));
```

What the heck is going on here? Math is a top-level class, so I don't think I should be getting an error like this. Is it possible to somehow "break" the Math class? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited from discussion below*

The [compiler error reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html) says that "You are calling a method that is not defined." `Math` not being defined sounds pretty serious - if you have no idea of why this occurred, maybe reinstall your SDK?

---

Original answer:

Does other Actionscript work for you? Is it only the `Math` class that is broken for you? If others are broken too, it's probably a build path configuration issue.

If not, check to make sure that you don't have any class named `Math` in the package that might interfere.

Comment: Oh, hello again, Allen. :P Anyway, yes, it's only the Math class that is broken, and I have no other Math AS files. I've been writing this, and it's been going fine, but as soon as I introduce the Math class, it falls apart. I admit I'm quite baffled by all this.

Comment: Hi Jake! Are you sure that `initPos.x`, etc are `Number`s? The statement works for me quite fine when I use Numbers for the variables.

Comment: – Yes, they are Numbers. I have performed various other tests, with no luck. I even just created a new AS3 document and just put the code `trace(Math.sqrt(4));`. No luck, same error.

Comment: The [compilation error reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html) says that "You are calling a method that is not defined." `Math` not being defined sounds pretty serious - if you have no idea of why this occurred, maybe reinstall your SDK?

Comment: Yeah, I just did that (I have no time to look for the problem), and it seems to have fixed it. Still, this is so odd. I have no idea how it's even possible! Oh well, thanks for the help. Edit that into your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Edited, but it's not a great answer. I'd be fine if you wish to close/delete your question.